# Silex passing app and request to controller classes

Tags: silex

I want a simple way to access $app and $request in my controller classes. The document says to do this,

```
public function action(Application $app, Request $request) {
 // Do something.
}
```

but it doesn't look right to have to inject $app and $request to every method. Is there a way to include $app and $request to every controller by default, maybe using the constructor? I'd like to be able to use it as $this->app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Controllers as Services](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html) part of the documentation you can see how to inject dependencies to controller classes via the constructor - in that case a repository.

Comment: I tried using the controller service but I can't inject the Request. I tried this... $app['posts.controller'] = $app->share(function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return new PostController($app, $request);
});

Comment: Access the request via `$app["request"]`.

Comment: Just a small side note: In Silex 2.X `$app['request']` changed to `$app['request_stack']->getCurrentRequest()`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible :

Create a `ControllerResolver.php` somewhere in your project and put this inside :

```
namespace MyProject;

use Silex\ControllerResolver as BaseControllerResolver;

class ControllerResolver extends BaseControllerResolver
{
    protected function instantiateController($class)
    {
        return new $class($this->app);
    }
}
```

Then register it in your app (before `$app->run();`):

```
$app['resolver'] = function ($app) {
    return new \MyProject\ControllerResolver($app, $app['logger']);
};
```

Now you can create a base controller for your app, for example :

```
namespace MyProject;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

abstract class BaseController
{
    public $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function getParam($key)
    {
        $postParams = $this->app['request_stack']->getCurrentRequest()->request->all();
        $getParams = $this->app['request_stack']->getCurrentRequest()->query->all();

        if (isset($postParams[$key])) {
            return $postParams[$key];
        } elseif (isset($getParams[$key])) {
            return $getParams[$key];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function render($view, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $response = new Response();
        return $response->setContent($this->app['twig']->render($view, $parameters));
    }

}
```

And extend it :

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // now you can use $this->app

        return $this->render('home.html.twig');
    }
}
```